# "precondition failure: type check failed: 104, expected Image, got _ColorInvertEffect" with .colorInvert() in SwiftUI on iOS 13.4

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an app that's using the `.colorInvert()` modifier on a SwiftUI Image that was working as intended on iOS 13.3.1 and prior, but results in a crash on iOS 13.4. The only console error displayed is:

```
“precondition failure: type check failed: 104, expected Image, got _ColorInvertEffect”
```

It still runs as intended (with no crash) on simulator and devices running iOS 13.1 - 13.3.1

Except of code below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import RealmSwift

struct ReleaseDetailView: View {
    @State private var witnessSignatureImage: Image?
    ...

    var release: ModelRelease

var body: some View {
Form {
...
Section(header: Text("WITNESS")) {
                    Text("Name: \(release.witnessFirstName) \(release.witnessLastName)")
                    if witnessSignatureImage != nil {
                        if colorScheme == .dark {
                            witnessSignatureImage?
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .colorInvert()
                        } else {
                            witnessSignatureImage?
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        }
                    } else {
                        Text("Witness signature not found.")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }
                } .onAppear(perform: self.loadWitnessSignatureImage)
            }
...
    func loadWitnessSignatureImage() {
        guard let witnessSignatureData = release.witnessSignature?.storedData() else {
            return
        }

        let img = UIImage(data: witnessSignatureData)
        witnessSignatureImage = Image(uiImage: img!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine here with 11.4 (11E146) / iOS 13.4. So you observe crash everywhere or only on device? Would you show demo code?

Comment: I added example code (the only thing omitted is some pretty generic text displayed in a form) to the original post. I'm seeing this everywhere - simulator and on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working around this by changing my `loadWitnessSignatureImage` function to invert the colors of the `UIImage` using an extension of `UIImage`

The revised loadImage function:

```
    func loadWitnessSignatureImage() {
        guard let witnessSignatureData = release.witnessSignature?.storedData() else {
            return
        }

        let img = UIImage(data: witnessSignatureData)
        if colorScheme == .dark {
            witnessSignatureImage = Image(uiImage: img!.invertedColors()!)
        } else {
            witnessSignatureImage = Image(uiImage: img!)

        }
    }
```

The `.invertedColors()` extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    func invertedColors() -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
        let ciImage = CoreImage.CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert") else { return nil }
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
        guard let outputImageCopy = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: outputImageCopy, scale: self.scale, orientation: .up)
    }
}
```